# Set DNS options during docker build

Tags: docker, dns

Due to local network configuration I have to add --dns and --dns-search options to my docker run commands like so:

```
docker run --dns XX.XX.1.1 --dns-search companydomain -t mycontainer
```

However docker build doesn't have the same options. Is there a way to specify these options during build?

Comment: You can try putting extra stuff into `/etc/resolv.conf` in your `Dockerfile`

Comment: More or less the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network

Comment: I strongly recommend using `docker build --add-host` instead of fiddling with DNS if possible. Most of the time you want to access e.g. a private registry to build a docker image and then the --add-host most likely will be sufficient. e.g.

`docker build --add-host my-private-npm-registry.company.com:192.168.12.44`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The docker build uses the DNS settings of the docker engine running on the host. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184773/596285) for steps to update the DNS settings on the engine.

Answer (score 24):

**Dockerfile-based solution**

You can also fix the DNS lookup problem on a per `RUN`-command level:

```
RUN echo "nameserver XX.XX.1.1" > /etc/resolv.conf && \ 
    echo "search companydomain" >> /etc/resolv.conf && \    
    command_depending_on_dns_resolution
```

Keep in mind: This will only change the DNS resolution behaviour for this one `RUN` command, as changes to the `/etc/resolv.conf` are not persistent (I could not find any official reference for this behaviour beside from a [comment from of one of the core Docker engineers](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25537#issuecomment-238873885) Brian Goff).

Comment: permission denied? even when running docker as root

Comment: probably you should open a new question with your problem, because for me this still works (tested with v18.06.1-ce and API v1.38)

Comment: This looks like the solution I need but I saw permission issue too

Comment: This used to work - I had it programmed on many internal docker builds on my company network - as of the latest version of docker it looks like the /etc/resolv.conf doesn't work anymore as they restrict the file to read only - just coming back to this post to inform people who find this in 2021.

Comment: @Cody Yes i am getting this error: `/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/resolv.conf: Read-only file system`. What is the method now?

Comment: No longer useful because of the Read-only error, use dear BMitch 's solution.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can also pass the host network option

```
docker build --network=host -t mycontainer:tag .
```