# wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com'

Tags: dockerfile, redhat, alpine-linux

I am building my dockerfile using Redhat UBI image, and when I build the image I get the wget: unable to resolve host address'github.com'.

I have tried adding a different URL that does not start with GitHub and that works. Not sure what the problem is.

Below are the errors logs i get when i build the docker file with : wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com'

```
Step 11/25 : RUN set -ex;   apk update;   apk add -f acl dirmngr gpg lsof procps wget netcat gosu tini;   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;   cd /usr/local/bin; wget -nv https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach; chmod 755 jattach;   echo >jattach.sha512 "d8eedbb3e192a8596c08efedff99b9acf1075331e1747107c07cdb1718db2abe259ef168109e46bd4cf80d47d43028ff469f95e6ddcbdda4d7ffa73a20e852f9  jattach";   sha512sum -c jattach.sha512; rm jattach.sha512
 ---> Running in 3ad58c40b25a
+ apk update
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v20200917-1125-g7274a98dfc [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main]
v20200917-1124-g01e8cb93ff [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community]
OK: 13174 distinct packages available
+ apk add -f acl dirmngr gpg lsof procps wget netcat gosu tini
(1/12) Installing libacl (2.2.53-r0)
(2/12) Installing acl (2.2.53-r0)
(3/12) Installing lsof (4.93.2-r0)
(4/12) Installing libintl (0.20.2-r0)
(5/12) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.2_p20200918-r1)
(6/12) Installing ncurses-libs (6.2_p20200918-r1)
(7/12) Installing libproc (3.3.16-r0)
(8/12) Installing procps (3.3.16-r0)
(9/12) Installing tini (0.19.0-r0)
(10/12) Installing libunistring (0.9.10-r0)
(11/12) Installing libidn2 (2.3.0-r0)
(12/12) Installing wget (1.20.3-r1)
Executing busybox-1.32.0-r3.trigger
OK: 9 MiB in 26 packages
+ rm -rf '/var/lib/apt/lists/*'
+ cd /usr/local/bin
+ wget -nv https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach
wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com'
The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex;   apk update;   apk add -f acl dirmngr gpg lsof procps wget netcat gosu tini;   rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;   cd /usr/local/bin; wget -nv https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach; chmod 755 jattach;   echo >jattach.sha512 "d8eedbb3e192a8596c08efedff99b9acf1075331e1747107c07cdb1718db2abe259ef168109e46bd4cf80d47d43028ff469f95e6ddcbdda4d7ffa73a20e852f9  jattach";   sha512sum -c jattach.sha512; rm jattach.sha512' returned a non-zero code: 4
```

Here is my docker file that I have which I build to create the image

```
FROM alpine: edge as BUILD


LABEL maintainer="Project Ranger team <mbyousaf@deloitte.co.uk>"
LABEL repository="https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr"

ARG SOLR_VERSION="8.6.2"
ARG SOLR_SHA512="0a43401ecf7946b2724da2d43896cd505386a8f9b07ddc60256cb586873e7e58610d2c34b1cf797323bf06c7613b109527a15105dc2a11be6f866531a1f2cef6"
ARG SOLR_KEYS="E58A6F4D5B2B48AC66D5E53BD4F181881A42F9E6"
# If specified, this will override SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER and all ASF mirrors. Typically used downstream for custom builds
ARG SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL

# Override the solr download location with e.g.:
#   docker build -t mine --build-arg SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER=http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr .
ARG SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER


RUN set -ex; \
  apk add --update; \
  apk add -f install acl dirmngr gpg lsof procps wget netcat gosu tini; \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
  cd /usr/local/bin; wget -nv https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach; chmod 755 jattach; \
  echo >jattach.sha512 "d8eedbb3e192a8596c08efedff99b9acf1075331e1747107c07cdb1718db2abe259ef168109e46bd4cf80d47d43028ff469f95e6ddcbdda4d7ffa73a20e852f9  jattach"; \
  sha512sum -c jattach.sha512; rm jattach.sha512
```

Comment: If you encounter an error, please remember to show the actual error (ideally with enough lead-up that shows the trigger for that error).

Comment: apologies have added error logs

Comment: This does not seem to be a Red Hat UBI image. Where are you building the image? Locally?

Comment: yes building this locally on my machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would check whether you can resolve github.com on your host where you're doing this build, and I would `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to see the resolvers of your host.  If github.com resolves on your host (which you can see via `nslookup github.com`), then I would try to use the resolvers explicitly by either configuring the Docker daemon to use it as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184496/configuring-options-for-docker-run/44184773#44184773) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151129/network-calls-fail-during-image-build-on-corporate-network) or I would try to do it at a per command level as suggested in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184661/set-dns-options-during-docker-build), which is kind of creative.

```
RUN echo "nameserver XX.XX.XX.XX" > /etc/resolv.conf && \    
    command_depending_on_dns_resolution
```