# confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest' returned a non-zero code: 7

Tags: mongodb, docker, apache-kafka

What I want is to run the official `mongodb/mongo-kafka` connector from the [mongodb github](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-kafka). There is no place to issue the problem and solve it in that repository and I didn't find any solution to fix the problem.

The problem is whenever I run `docker-compose up` and the docker starts to build the containers, during that process I face with the following error:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN  confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest
 ---> Running in b54abee6b78c
Running in a "--no-prompt" mode 
java.net.UnknownHostException: api.hub.confluent.io 

Error: Unknown error 
ERROR: Service 'connect' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:latest' returned a non-zero code: 7
```

**NOTE:** The only difference between my and the mongodb docker-compose file is that I have changed the version to 3.3 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you have a problem with hostnames resolution. It should be resolved to valid host name - check it with `nslookup` command, like this:

```
# nslookup api.hub.confluent.io
Server:     2a02:908:2:a::1
Address:    2a02:908:2:a::1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
api.hub.confluent.io    canonical name = plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.
Name:   plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.8.156.136
Name:   plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 13.57.110.164
```

if it will persist, try to change `/etc/resolv.conf` on your node, or modify Docker's DNS settings, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184496/configuring-options-for-docker-run/44184773#44184773).

Comment: Hi Alex, `nslookup` command returned `Server:8.8.8.8 Address:8.8.8.8#53`

`Non-authoritative answer:api.hub.confluent.io canonical name = plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com.
Name: plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 13.57.110.164
Name: plugin-registry.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
Address: 52.8.156.136
` and there is no error.

Comment: I just build the image without any problem. Try to explicitly setup DNS in Docker.