# NPM install failing in Docker - "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I am trying to run a demo VS Code extension from a Github repository locally. It is inside a container. I am currently on Windows, using Docker Desktop. When I try to run docker, it gives me this error:

```
139.5 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-string-width/node-string-width_4.2.3%2b%7ecs13.2.3-1_all.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to :80: dial tcp :80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [IP: 80]
139.5 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-wrap-ansi/node-wrap-ansi_8.0.1%2b%7e8.0.1-3_all.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to :80: dial tcp :80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [IP:  80]
139.5 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-cliui/node-cliui_7.0.4%2brepack%2b%7ecs3.1.0-4_all.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to :80: dial tcp :80: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [IP: 80]
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt install -y npm" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

So far, I have only tried turning on the `Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS.` option on Docker Desktop, and restarting my machine and router, but it still produces the same error.

How can I fix this error? Thank you in advance!

Edit: I tried adding "8.8.8.8" to my Docker Daemon as my DNS, as suggested below, and it gave me multiple errors that look like the following:

```
210.7 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/node-promise-retry/node-promise-retry_2.0.1-4_all.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: resolving host deb.debian.org: lookup deb.debian.org: getaddrinfow: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did 
not receive a response from an authoritative server. [IP: 80]
```

The Dockerfile is this:

```
# Step 1: Use official lightweight Python image as base OS.
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

# ARG GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/usr/src/app/serviceAccount.json"

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies

# Bundle app source
COPY app /usr/src/app
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="./serviceAccount.json"
ENV SENTRY_SDK_DSN="https://36508a31dbb3468994b7ae470704ce10@o718840.ingest.sentry.io/5783806"

WORKDIR pdf2jsonl
ENV PATH pdf2jsonl/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
RUN sed -i 's/token in cache/token in cache \&\& typeof cache[token] === "string"/g' node_modules/gpt-3-encoder/Encoder.js

WORKDIR ..
# Step 3. Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/pdf2jsonl/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=dev
      - TESTING=0
      - GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/app/serviceAccount.json
```

Comment: Set your “DNS Server” to “fixed: 8.8.8.8”, in the network tab of docker settings. [You can add these options to the docker daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184496/configuring-options-for-docker-run/44184773#44184773).

Comment: I have done that, and I encountered a different error. I've edited my post above. Thank you for your suggestion! @WEBjuju

Comment: i think that your vm's networking can't get to the wan. can you open a shell to it and try to `wget google.com` or any curl command to a www site and be sure your vm can reach the internet? _btw, if you found my comment helpful, could you click the "up" caret please?_

Answer (score 0):

Your `apt update` step is possibly cached (causing the install step to request incorrect endpoints). Try running the build without the cache or prune your system: `docker system prune --all` and try the build again.